# How to handle KMZ files in Apple's MapKit

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, mapkit

I am trying to pull some KMZ files over the net and overlay them on Google Maps.  I have looked at Apple's kmlParser example, which is very close to what I want to do, however in its current form it can only parse KML files.  Most of the RSS feeds and google data on the net however seems to be in KMZ format (which I believe is a zipped version of KML files).  Is it possible to unzip the KMZ files programmatically in Xcode?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
// Locate the path to the route.kml file in the application's bundle
// 
//NSURL *path = @"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/eqs7day-age.kmz";
//NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/eqs7day-age.kmz"];
//kml = [[KMLParser parseKMLAtURL:url] retain];    // and parse it with the KMLParser.
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"doc" ofType:@"kml"];
kml = [[KMLParser parseKMLAtPath:path] retain];    // and parse it with the KMLParser.


// Add all of the MKOverlay objects parsed from the KML file to the map.
NSArray *overlays = [kml overlays];
[map addOverlays:overlays];
```

In the above code snipped, I have also tried using the NSURL method (commented out lines), but it doesn't work.  I have to manually download the KMZ file, unzip it and then feed it to the KML parser and ideally I would like to do that within the program itself.

I will appreciate any help or guidance on how to solve this problem.

Soofi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that KMZ files are simply zipped up KML files. The appropriate part of the documentation is [here](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmzarchives.html).

The Apple KML example is very simplistic. If you want a fuller featured parser, I would recommend [libKML](http://code.google.com/p/libkml/). It has full support for the KML standard, and handles KML and KMZ files. The only catch is that it is written in C++, and uses intrusive pointers which can be a bit painful in Obj-C.

If you really want to write your own parser, and just need a way to unzip files, [ZipKit](https://github.com/kolpanic/ZipKit) should work for you.

Comment: Thank..ZipKit works. It is a bit of work to integrate that code into the project.  You are also right, Apple's KML example is simple but for my application it was enough.  I used zipkit to unzip and feed the result to Apple's KML parser.

Comment: You should update your link to ZipKit with this own as this is the new link https://github.com/kolpanic/ZipKit

Answer (score 3):

hey i would like to recommend KML Viewer ,

just download the project and you will find everything there

link : [KML Viewer](https://github.com/FLCLjp/KML-Viewer)

i know this ans is late but its for people who want reference :)

Comment: Hi, I am unable to found the project on above link, can you please update the link?

Comment: May be this will help you https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html